# PHP Regular expression return submatches as array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, function, dom

I have a question regarding regular expressions.

What I want to do is use only one regular expression to match part of string and get out what's inside divided. Don't know how to explain it, so will write an example

Example html to parse

```
<div class="test">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
    <span>d</span>
</div>
<div class="test2">
    <span>aa</span>
    <span>bb</span>
    <span>cc</span>
    <span>dd</span>
</div>
```

I want to preg_match(_all) only span values from .test

Normally, I would use

```
preg_match('/<div class="test">(.*?)<\/div>/', $html, $matches)
preg_match_all('/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/',  $matches[1],  $matches2)
```

And then use another preg_match_all to get out values.

However, i was wondering if there is a way to make a subpattern in a pattern that would automaticly first match divs and then all spans and would return resulat as array.

Is something like this possible? I couldn't find it anywhere. Maybe I don't know how it is technically called.

Edit:
Output I would like to get (changed data sample), but **only with one preg_match or preg_match_all call**:

```
array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `DOMParser` instead of going for regular expressions..

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'test')
    {
        foreach($tag->getElementsByTagName('span') as $stag)
        {
        $val[]=$stag->nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
print_r($val);
```

#### Using an XPath Query.. (for the same)

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("*/div[@class='test']/span");
foreach($elements as $v)
{
    $arr[]=$v->nodeValue;
}
print_r($arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

<kbd>[Working Demo - Normal DOM Way](https://eval.in/138798)</kbd>

<kbd>[Working Demo - XPath Way](https://eval.in/138804)</kbd>

Comment: Nice solution, but I'm scrapping some from site, that is not always the same. So it can differ

Comment: DOM is the right way to proceed with even in that case.. Can you post your expected output ?

Comment: I know DOM. But I want more to know if such regular expressions are possible. This question is more if such regexes exist.
gonna edit qeustin with expected output

Comment: Fine. In the meantime ,please read this [**article**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) by our Jeff Atwood. It says why you should not use Regex to parse HTML.

Comment: There are about 60 different templates. With different positioning dependable on entry type.
I got to get out data out of cache, since whole database is lost and cache is only what's left.
Only parts like adress/Type/Name are same.
Writing DOM walker for every template is gonna take long. Script is not going to be used every day work nor it is going to be distributed in any form. So it's one time script get data out that will parse 600 pages and will be removed. That's why I decided for preg_match instead of DOM.

Comment: @Gacek, I have modified the answer and demo and don't know if you are _really satisfied with that_

Comment: I totally forgot about getElementsByTagName. May as well use your approach ;). Ty.

But the other thing still interests me. If that is possible what I wanted. Fo find match and then get data out like that. I just want to know regexp more.

Comment: @Gacek, Added an XPath way too have a look.

Comment: It is and it is not what I was looking for. I was more interested in idea about multi-matching of matched area. But seems I shouldn't give HTML data as an example :). But this is still very very good answer to question if someone was interested in parsing HTML data and not in regular expressions itself.

Comment: Wish I had understood what you are really looking for :) . Please post a detailed question soon and really wanna know what you are upto. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Post it as a new question?

Comment: @Gacek, Maybe you can unaccept the answer and wait and see if someone else posts a good answer. If not, you can ask a new question with more detailed information.

Comment: Especially for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184567/using-regular-expression-subpattern-to-instead-of-using-regular-expression-2-tim

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

`/<span>([^<]*)<\/span>/` with `preg_match_all`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/yD6gM0

Comment: I want only matches from div with .test and not ones from .test2