# Using regular expression subpattern to instead of using regular expression 2 times in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm interested if its possible to make include subpattern (child pattern) into a another pattern that would allow me to convert those 2 preg_match and preg_match_all into one preg_match/preg_match_all.

```
<?php

$data = 'office phones tel1 6665555998 tel2 555666888 tel3 555688855 home phones tel1 555222555 tel2 555222444 tel3 555666888';

preg_match('/phones(.*)home phones/', $data, $matches); // 1st operation
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{4,12}/',  $matches[1],  $matches); // 2nd operation

var_dump($matches);

// Question is: How to get same output with just only one preg_match

preg_match('/phones(SUBPATTERN)home phones/', $data, $result_data);

// Where SUBPATTERN is a pattern that would do exactly what 2nd operation did
// so $result_data contains what does $matches (array structure can be different can be 3 dimmensional array not only 2)
```

Example data: https://eval.in/138817

Note: This question is another approach to get answer which had different data: [PHP Regular expression return submatches as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183647/php-regular-expression-return-submatches-as-array/23183691?noredirect=1#comment35458686_23183691)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\G` anchor with a global research (preg_match_all):

```
$pattern = '~(?:office phones|\G(?!\A)) tel\d+ \K\d{4,12}~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

`\G` is an anchor for the position in the string after the last match, when there is not yet match (at the begining) it is equivalent to the `\A` anchor.

`\K` is used to remove the left part of the match from match result.

Comment: Seems to be what I was looking for! Must analyze it carefully and understand it better :) Result seems to be what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookahead `(?=.*?home)`

```
<?php

$data = 'office phones tel1 6665555998 tel2 555666888 tel3 555688855 home phones tel1 555222555 tel2 555222444 tel3 555666888';
preg_match_all('/([\d]{2,})(?=.*?home)/', $data, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => 6665555998
    [1] => 555666888
    [2] => 555688855
)

?>
```

**PHP**
http://ideone.com/nryjIm

**REGEX**
http://regex101.com/r/oV7mO2

**This is an update based on your comment:**

```
    $pnlist = "office phones tel1 6665555998 tel2 555666888 tel3 555688855 home phones tel1 555222555 tel2 555222444 tel3 555666888";

/*1*/    preg_match_all('/(?:office)(.*?)(?:home)/', $pnlist, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
/*2*/    preg_match_all('/([\d]{2,})/', $result[1][0], $pn, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    print_r($pn[1]);

/*
Array ( 
 [0] => 6665555998
 [1] => 555666888
 [2] => 555688855
 ) 
*/
```

You can change the first `preg_match_all` start(**office**) and ending (**home**) values to whatever you want, then you match the phone numbers on that group.

Comment: That's also nice approach. But it seems to end searching and 'home' string. What if there were other phones Before office? Like:
other phones tel1 555222555 tel2 555222444 tel3 555666888 office phones [...] ?

Comment: You'll need to change the string `home` to whatever is appropriate for you.

Comment: Yeah. That works. but as stated in question. Only 1 preg_match or preg_match_all. This question is more out of curiosity than to solve particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = 'office phones tel1 6665555998 tel2 555666888 tel3 555688855 home phones tel1 555222555 tel2 555222444 tel3 555666888';


preg_match_all('/[0-9]{4,12}/', $data,  $matches); // 2nd operation

var_dump($matches);
```

Like this [example](https://eval.in/138825)

Comment: But I want ONLY Office phones.And your code gets home phones also.